# Hosting a Vue.js app on a Node.js Express - on cPanel - only loading index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, cpanel

I'm hosting a Vue.js app on a Node.js Express app which works perfectly when running locally. When I upload it to cPanel, it only loads the index.html leaving me with a blank page and several 404 errors for all the "missing" files which are sitting next to it.

**NODE: app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const path = __dirname + '/client';

const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(path));

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send("API TEST!");
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

**NODE: package.json**

```
{
  "name": "basic_node_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Basic Node App to serve something.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

**VUE: index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>basic_vue_app</title>
    <link href="/js/app.62f5dd50.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="/js/chunk-vendors.2b964eb5.js" rel="preload" as="script">
</head>
<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but basic_vue_app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it
            to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/js/chunk-vendors.2b964eb5.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.62f5dd50.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**VUE: App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>THIS IS A GOOD TEST</label>
    <label>API WORKS -> {{ apiresult }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      apiresult: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    Axios.get("/test").then((res) => {
      this.apiresult = res.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

VUE: dist folder

- **JS folder**
- app.[id].js
- app.[id].js.map
- chunck-vendors.[id].js
- chunck-vendors.[id].js.map
- **favicon.ico**
- **index.html**

on my cPanel, this is my structure:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glaVN.png)

I'm running the node app like this:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyzMp.png)

Finally, my problem. When I run it locally I get this on my browser:
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arGjg.png)

But when I deploy it and run it on cPanel I get:
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Cyw.png)

Thanks in advance for all your help.
Best regards,

Comment: you have to build it, look at the index.html file, all the `<%-` etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer.My "vue dist folder" is already the result of building my vue app.

Comment: Is there no one who can help me?